# How to use mock.patch() for Django request object?

Tags: django, python-mock

I am trying to overwrite HTTP_POST to certain string of a request object inside a view:

```
with patch('django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest') as request:
    request.META = {'HTTP_HOST': 'www.abc.com'}
    resp = self.client.get('/')
```

But obviously it's not working since it's complaining `HTTP_POST` KeyError

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a mock object, you should probably use [`django.test.client.RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) to generate a request object.

Comment: I don't have a particular view to test since this is a library, I just want to test the middleware, but looks like I might just test the middleware directly without going through the request

Comment: You'd still need a `request` object. Another option is to simply use `django.http.request.HttpRequest`, which is easier to construct than a `WSGIRequest`. Both methods are specifically tailored to testing, and are frequently used throughout Django's test suite.